# Disable contact form input fields after submit

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, contact-form-7

This is my first time asking a question.

I have a website where you log in, and after login, you can submit a form. (Contact form 7).

I want the input fields to disable after the user have submitted a form, so he can only submit that form 1 time (I have 6 forms total).

My first thought was to insert a row in the database with the username and 0 (Not submitted) or 1 (Submitted).  If 1, then disable form, or if 0, then you can submit a form.

My problem is that i can't get wordpress to insert anything in the database.
I tried this plugin at first:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-cfdb7/

and it kind of worked, but now the plugin doesn't insert anything in the database anymore. I have no idea why. I haven't changed anything.

When i insert some php / sql code in functions.php, then when i submit the form, it's just loading. Nothing happens.

Comment: "When i insert some php / sql code in functions.php" Please add the code to your question

Comment: Hello en Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I think maybe https://wordpress.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask this question?

Comment: The code is here:

if (isset($_POST['your-mail'])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `FB0WvN_db7_forms` (isset, username) VALUES ('1', '$username')";

And yes, i have set the  $username = wp_get_current_user();

Comment: Cody604. You're right. I willt try :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code to your input tag which you want to disable

```
<?php echo (isset($_POST['submit'])) ? 'disabled' : ""; ?> 
//if submit method is POST else use $_GET for get method
```